# NullPointerException when reading from external properties file

Tags: java, spring

I'm trying to externalize a properties file. Right now, I'm testing by placing my properties file under my user profile folder, but I'm getting a `NullPointerException`. To be more specific, the `System.out.println` statement isn't being displayed in the console, which leads me to think that maybe it's the environment variable that's triggering the `NullPointerException`. I have also ensured that I placed the properties file in the correct path. Here is part of the code:

```
@PropertySource("file:${USERPROFILE}/test.properties")
public MyClass{

 private static Environment e;

 public static void main(String[] args){
    System.out.println("Test properties file: " + e.getProperty("myKey");
 }

}
```

Properties file:

```
myKey=testvalue
```

And this line in my dispatcher servlet xml file :

```
<context:property-placeholder location="classpath*:query.properties, file:${USERPROFILE}/test.properties"/>
```

Where am I going wrong here? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Look like `e` is null.   Where do you initialize its value?

Comment: @MFisherKDX, I tried initializing it to null where I declared it. But I get the NullPointerException with or without initializing it there, unless I'm missing something, is there somewhere else it needs to be initialized in Spring. I'm new to Spring

Comment: Correct. That would be the expected behavior. .https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it. I don't know anything about Spring.

Comment: Have you tried injecting the application context and then saying: Envrionment e = context.getEnvrionment()? This should avoid null on e variable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like your Environment object is not loaded and binded and is null. Try to inject the Environment variable using @Resource

Replace

```
private static Environment e;
```

With

```
@Resource
private static Environment e;
```